# Is py_trees library of python which is used for creating behavior trees only used in ROS or can it be run on some other platform as well?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ros

I have come across a library called py_trees which provides me with the classes and functions to create a behavior tree , but I am using windows 10 and I am wondering if ROS(which operates on Ubuntu) is required to use py_trees.

I have gone through the github pages of py_trees and in most of them it has been integrated with ROS and therefore I am wondering if we can use it in windows or not.

Answer (score 0):

No, ROS is not required for py_trees; but it is useful with ROS. There is actually a separate package that *specifically* integrates it with ROS. It’ll work fine on Windows and can be installed via pip.